# Grails 2.4.4 coverage springSecurityService

Tags: grails, spring-security, integration-testing, cobertura

I have grails 2.4.4 and Cobertura as covert test. I have this code to test:

```
def viewMailTemplates(){
    User user = User.findByEmail(springSecurityService.authentication.principal)
    def token = user.activationToken
    def urlActivacion = request.getScheme() + '://' + request.getServerName() +":"+ request.getServerPort() + createLink(controller: "user", action: "activation", params: [token: token])

    def srcImage = request.getScheme() + '://' + request.getServerName() +":"+ request.getServerPort()+ "/assets/logoOlu.jpg"
    render(view: 'mailTemplates/_activationES', model: [srcImage: srcImage, urlActivacion: urlActivacion])
}
```

And I have this test:

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor( UserController )
@Mock([UserController, User])

class UserControllerSpec extends Specification {

 void "Test the viewMailTemplates action returns the correct model"() {
      when: "The viewMailTemplates action is executed"
        controller.viewMailTemplates()
        then: "The model is correct"
        status == 405
        }
```

But the problem is test mode can´t access to data base and  pass this test because  springSecurityService=null

If I do something like "User.get(1)" it results null, even I have this user and the program (in develop)  works fine with database in localhost with Mysql

How can I pass this test? How can create a new springSecurityService for this test?

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests, by design,  do not connect to the database, instead they mock storage for domains in memory. (On the other hand, integration tests do connect to a real database.)

For each unit test you must "manually" save the instances required by your test. To avoid repetition, you can use the `setup` method and save instances that will be used by all the test in the class.

Finally, you can mock `SpringSecurityService` as suggested by Mike W.

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor( UserController )
@Mock([UserController, User])

class UserControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
        new User(username:'test', email:'demo@test.com').save(flush:true)
        assert User.count() == 1

        controller.springSecurityService = [authentication:[principal: 'demo@test.com']]
    }

    void "Test the viewMailTemplates action returns the correct model"() {
        when: "The viewMailTemplates action is executed"
            controller.viewMailTemplates()
        then: "The model is correct"
            status == 405
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it gives me this error:

`Condition not satisfied:

User.count() == 1
     |       |
     0       false

Expected :1

Actual   :0`

I think is about can be access to database while testing (integration or unit, I tried both). Any suggestion?

Comment: It means the user was not saved in the previous line. I just used `username` and `email` properties as an example. You need to correctly set all the properties defined in your specific `User` domain.

Comment: You can also use `save(flush:true, failOnError:true)` to see the validations that are failing and preventing from saving the `User`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make springSecurityService a map of maps like:

```
void "Test the viewMailTemplates action returns the correct model"() {
    given:
        controller.springSecurityService = [authentication:[principal: 'email_address_of_user_in_db']]
    when:
         controller.viewMailTemplates()
    then: "The model is correct"
        status == 405
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but user returns null. I think because it´s searching in the DB but really cannot connect or somethig happend that can´t read DB in tests

Comment: Have you actually added a user in the db in your setup method or bootstrap or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I try to read this user from DB, or create in test, os create and save in test (and it didn´t) but nothing works